# R: Finding Quantile and Natural breaks for vector

Tags: r, graph, colors, statistics

I have a vector with urbanization values (in percent) of different countries. I am trying to classify this data into 4 to 5 categories, and color my graph objects by category. The vector I am using is 99 terms long and I would like the output to be the same length with 5 unique values.

Example vector:

```
myVec <- c(0.2, 0.6, 0.34, 0.78, 0.66, 0.5, 0.8, 0.99)
```

I tried something like this, but breaks were at random and not by quantity:

```
split(network_object$nodes$X.Urban,  ceiling(seq_along(network_object$nodes$X.Urban) / 4))
```

I have ploted the histogram and it is varies a lot, so there's no way to normalize it.

Comment: I just installed BAMMtools so I got it

Comment: You need add a `dput()` to your question so we can see the data. Why doesn't the `quantile()` function works in your case ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.